# Magento2.3.2: url shows http instead of https

Tags: magento2.3.2, ssl, https, secure, encryption-key

I am using magento2.3.2

I'd like to use the https in the url to maintain the website secure. I haven't purchase any ssl certificate. I have used encrypted certificate and installed via putty. There shows https is enabled to your site. But i haven't found the url is with https.

Website url : [Depoto website][1]

I have instance in aws-lightsail and ubuntu server.

[1]: http://depoto.com[image]

Answer (score 3):

First Check status:

```
select * from `core_config_data` WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = "web/secure/use_in_frontend";

select * from `core_config_data` WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = "web/secure/use_in_adminhtml";
```

Enable ssl:

```
php bin/magento web/secure/use_in_frontend 1
php bin/magento web/secure/use_in_adminhtml 1
```

or

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = '1' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = "web/secure/use_in_frontend";

UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = '1' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = "web/secure/use_in_adminhtml";
```

Disable ssl:

```
php bin/magento web/secure/use_in_frontend 0
php bin/magento web/secure/use_in_adminhtml 0
```

or

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = '0' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = "web/secure/use_in_frontend";

UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = '0' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = "web/secure/use_in_adminhtml";
```

Finally

```
php bin/magento c:f
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to set the both configuration to Yes:

   ```
   web/secure/use_in_frontend
   web/secure/use_in_adminhtml
   ```
2. Now set URL value to https :

   ```
   bin/magento config:set web/secure/base_url https://depoto.com/
   ```
3. Now run the following commands from the Magento root.

   ```
   php bin/magento cache:clean
   php bin/magento cache:flush
   php bin/magento indexer:reindex
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
   sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if both of these configuration is set to 1 (true).

```
web/secure/use_in_frontend
web/secure/use_in_adminhtml
```

by executing

```
bin/magento config:show [config_path]
```

If one of them is not set (a message similar to `Configuration for path: "web/secure/use_in_frontend" doesn't exist`) or the value is `0`, you need to enable by executing

```
bin/magento config:set [config_path] 1
```

After both configuration are set to 1, you need to make sure that your secure base URL is set to `https://depoto.com/` instead of `http://depoto.com/`. Check it by executing

```
bin/magento config:show web/secure/base_url
```

If the value is not what you want (which means other than `https://depoto.com/`), you need to change it by executing

```
bin/magento config:set web/secure/base_url https://depoto.com/
```

Flush your cache after setting the proper configuration by executing

```
bin/magento cache:flush
```

After that, check your website if it is redirecting to https.

Comment: I have followed the steps which you have described above and flushed the cache too. When i change my base url from http to https, then the site is not getting opened. https://prnt.sc/uccfnp. then i reverted to http. then its fine as before